# How to turn a python file to an exe file, so that the code can be masked

Tags: python, linux, executable

I have a python cryptography program that i created and I want to mask the code so it cannot be read by anyone. What is the best way to do that in Linux and maybe in windows? 
I suspect i should turn it to an exe file and if so how ??? 
thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont know what is the best way but you can create a .exe with **http://www.pyinstaller.org/**

Comment: The only thing that should be hidden is the secret/private key. If it is a good algorithm, the code can be public. (and probably should be)

Comment: its not a good algo...but for what i want its fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert Python scripts into standalone executable using:

[PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) can be used to convert Python programs into stand-alone executables, under Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, Solaris and AIX. It is one of the recommended converters.

[py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) converts Python scripts into only executable in Windows platform.

[Cython](http://cython.org/) is a static compiler for both the Python programming language and the extended Cython programming language.